# How to run Clojure code on Sublime Text 2?

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2

I wrote a script code of Clojure like this:

`(print "test")`

And when I pressed Shift+Ctrl+B I got this:

`[Error 2]`

`[cmd:  [u'lein', u'compile', u':all']]`

`[dir:  D:\Document\ACM-ICPC\Code\PKU]`

`[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;...]`

`[Finished]`

so,how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I use [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) when developing Clojure on SublimeText. It works, it supports other languages (CoffeScript, F#, Haskell ..), highly configurable and you will get a colored REPL!

I recommend to give it a try.

Comment: I have installed `SublimeREPL` by using `Package Control`,And I typed `(+ 1 2)` after `user=> `,It just jumped to next line but printed nothing...Is there something I need to configure?  _Sorry,forgive my poor English_

Answer (score 0):

Seems like command `lein compile :all` is not what you need to run single script.

You can install `lein exec` plugin by adding line `{:user {:plugins [[lein-exec "0.3.1"]]}}` to your `%USERPROFILE%\.lein\profiles.clj` file.

And then add new Sublime build system or change existing with something like `['cmd': [u'lein', u'exec', '$file']]`

Comment: eh..It changed to be this `[cmd:  [u'lein', u'exec', u'D:\\Desktop\\try.clj']]`,Could you please show the the whole build system file?

Comment: @speedcell4 `{ "cmd": ["lein", "exec", "$file"] }` - working Clojure.sublime-build. I forgot to clarify: do you have [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) installed?

Comment: nothing happened...I don't know if i have installed Leiningen well,I downloaded it from [here](http://leiningen-win-installer.djpowell.net/),ran it and added `C:\Users\Administrator\.lein\bin` to PATH,is that all right?I can get the right reaction when I use `lein new project` in cmd.exe...

Comment: @speedcell4 does it work when you `cd` to `D:\Desktop` and type `lein exec try.clj`?

Comment: hmm, loaded in Windows and seems found the issue.. try to replace `"lein"` in build system by `"lein.bat"`